# PHP cPanel Pipe to Program

Tags: php, cpanel, email-forwarding

I'm forwarding all my school emails to another email via Outlook redirect rules. The problem is that the email is sent to me@schoolName.edu which then redirects to me@myDomain.com; however, when I get the e-mail, it doesn't say it was sent to me@schoolName.com, but instead it says it was sent to me@myDomain.com, so when I reply, it comes from myDomain instead of schoolName.

Is it possible to write a PHP script that will take all incoming messages, change who the "to" is in the header, before forwarding it on to me, so that when I'm on my mail, and hit respond, it will send from my school address?

Anybody?

Thanks

Comment: You understand that the TO part of the header is the message receiver. If you'd replace them all before forwarding all messages would go to that email. Also it is outlook that handles your sender name and address, you should be able to set sender in outlook settings somehow.